# Factorial calculation with threading takes too long to finish, How to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am trying to calculate whether a given number is prime or not with the formula :

(n-1)! mod n =? (n-1)

I must calculate the factorial with different threads and make them work simultaneously and control if they're all finished and if so then join them. By doing so I will be calculating factorial with different threads and then be able to take the modulo. However even though my code works fine with the small prime numbers it is taking too long to execute when the number is too big. I searched my code and couldn't really find alternative that can slow down the execution time. Here is my code :

```
import threading
import time

# GLOBAL VARIABLE
result = 1

# worker class in order to multiply on threads
class Worker:
    # initiating the worker class
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.jobs = []

    # the function that does  the actual multiplying
    def multiplier(self,beg,end):
        global result
        for i in range(beg,end+1):
            result*= i
            #print("\tresult updated with *{}:".format(i),result)
        #print("Calculating from {} to {}".format(beg,end)," : ",result)
    
    # appending threads to the object
    def append_job(self,job):
        self.jobs.append(job)

    # function that is to see the threads
    def see_jobs(self):
        return self.jobs

    # initiating the threads
    def initiate(self):
        for j in self.jobs:
            j.start()

    # finalizing and joining the threads
    def finalize(self):
        for j in self.jobs:
            j.join()

    # controlling the threads by blocking them untill all threads are asleep
    def work(self):
        while True:
            if 0 == len([t for t in self.jobs if t.is_alive()]):
                self.finalize()
                break
                
# this is the function to split the factorial into several threads
def splitUp(n,t):
    # defining the remainder and the whole 
    remainder, whole = (n-1) % t, (n-1) // t
    # deciding to tuple count
    tuple_count = whole if remainder == 0 else whole + 1
    # empty result list 
    result = []
    # iterating 
    beginning = 1
    end = (n-1) // t 
    for i in range(1,tuple_count+1):
        if i == tuple_count:
            result.append((beginning,n-1)) # if we are at the end, just append all to end
        else:
            result.append((beginning,end*i))
        beginning = end*i + 1
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads = 64
    number = 743
    splitted = splitUp(number,threads)

    worker = Worker()
    #print(worker.see_jobs())

    s = time.time()
    # creating the threads
    for arg in splitted:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=worker.multiplier(arg[0],arg[1]))
        worker.append_job(thread)

    worker.initiate()
    worker.work()
    e = time.time()
    print("result found with {} threads in {} secs\n".format(threads,e-s))
    if result % number == number-1:
        print("PRIME")
    else:
        print("NOT PRIME")
    

""" 
--------------------  REPORT  ------------------------

result found with 2 threads in 6.162530899047852 secs
result found with 4 threads in 0.29897499084472656 secs
result found with 16 threads in 0.009003162384033203 secs
result found with 32 threads in 0.0060007572174072266 secs
result found with 64 threads in 0.0029952526092529297 secs

note that: these results may differ from machine to machine
-------------------------------------------------------
"""
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which input (thread # and prime number)  and what time does it take, in the case you mention it's too slow?

Comment: The factorials can get quite huge pretty quickly, and then multiplying takes time. Have you considered multiplying modulo `n` instead of computing modulo value after all multiplications?

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you have a critical error in your code that you haven't reported or tried to trace:

```
======================== RESTART: ========================
result found with 2 threads in 5.800899267196655 secs

NOT PRIME
>>> 
======================== RESTART: ========================
result found with 64 threads in 0.002002716064453125 secs

PRIME
>>>
```

As the old saying goes, "if the program doesn't work, it doesn't matter how fast it is".

The only test case you've given is 743; if you want help to diagnose the logic error, please determine the minimal test and parallelism that causes the error, and post a separate question.

I suspect that it's with your `multplier` function, as you're working with an ill-advised global variable in parallel processing, and your multiply operation is *not* thread-safe.
In assembly terms, you have an unguarded region:

```
LOAD result
MUL  i
STORE result
```

If this is interleaved with the same work from another process, the result is virtually guaranteed to be wrong.  You have to make this a critical region.

---

Once you fix that, you still have your speed problem.  Factorial is the poster-child for recursion acceleration.  I see two obvious accelerants:

- Instead of that horridly slow multiplication loop, use `functools.reduce` to blast through your multiplication series.
- If you're going to loop the program with a series of inputs, then short-cut most of the calculations with [memoization](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php).  The example on the linked page benefits greatly from multiple-recursion; since factorial is linear, you'd need repeated application to take advantage of the technique.